# CS50 PSET4 - Help on Blur Filter

Tags: c, filter, cs50

So the problem is called "Filters" PSET4 and I was assigned to code a "blur" function that blurs an image. My code blurs the sample pictures but when I use the in-website tool to check the code it says that the program was "unable to blur a 3x3 and 4x4 pictures correctly". This is the code:

Here's what the tool says:
[4x4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okHbv.png)

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE image0[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image0[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) //topleft
            {
                float red00 = round((float)(image0[0][0].rgbtRed + image0[0][1].rgbtRed + image0[1][1].rgbtRed + image[1][0].rgbtRed) / 4);
                float green00 = round((image0[0][0].rgbtGreen + image0[0][1].rgbtGreen + image0[1][1].rgbtGreen + image[1][0].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                float blue00 = round((image0[0][0].rgbtBlue + image0[0][1].rgbtBlue + image0[1][1].rgbtBlue + image[1][0].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                image[0][0].rgbtRed = red00;
                image[0][0].rgbtGreen = green00;
                image[0][0].rgbtBlue = blue00;
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j == width - 1) //topright
            {
                float red01 = round((float)(image0[0][width - 1].rgbtRed + image0[0][width - 2].rgbtRed + image0[1][width - 2].rgbtRed + image0[1][width - 1].rgbtRed)
                / 4);
                float green01 = round((float)(image0[0][width - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[0][width - 2].rgbtGreen + image0[1][width - 2].rgbtGreen + image0[1][width - 1].rgbtGreen)
                / 4);
                float blue01 = round(((float)image0[0][width - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[0][width - 2].rgbtBlue + image0[1][width - 2].rgbtBlue + image0[1][width - 1].rgbtBlue)
                / 4);
                image[0][width - 1].rgbtRed = red01;
                image[0][width - 1].rgbtGreen = green01;
                image[0][width - 1].rgbtBlue = blue01;
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == 0) //bottomleft
            {
                float red10 = round((float)(image0[height - 1][0].rgbtRed + image0[height - 2][0].rgbtRed + image0[height - 2][1].rgbtRed + image0[height - 1][1].rgbtRed)
                / 4);
                float green10 = round((float)(image0[height - 1][0].rgbtGreen + image0[height - 2][0].rgbtGreen + image0[height - 2][1].rgbtGreen + image0[height - 1][1].rgbtGreen)
                / 4);
                float blue10 = round((float)(image0[height - 1][0].rgbtBlue + image0[height - 2][0].rgbtBlue + image0[height - 2][1].rgbtBlue + image0[height - 1][1].rgbtBlue)
                / 4);
                image[height - 1][0].rgbtRed = red10;
                image[height - 1][0].rgbtGreen = green10;
                image[height - 1][0].rgbtBlue = blue10;
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1) //bottomright
            {
                float red11 = round((float)(image0[height - 1][width - 1].rgbtRed + image0[height - 2][width - 1].rgbtRed + image0[height - 2][width - 2].rgbtRed
                + image0[height - 1][width - 2].rgbtRed) / 4);
                float green11 = round((float)(image0[height - 1][width - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[height - 2][width - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[height - 2][width - 2].rgbtGreen
                + image0[height - 1][width - 2].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                float blue11 = round((float)(image0[height - 1][width - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[height - 2][width - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[height - 2][width - 2].rgbtBlue
                + image0[height - 1][width - 2].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                image[height - 1][width - 1].rgbtRed = red11;
                image[height - 1][width - 1].rgbtGreen = green11;
                image[height - 1][width - 1].rgbtBlue = blue11;
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j != 0 && j != width - 1) //top
            {
                float redtop = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtRed + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image0[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image0[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                float greentop = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtGreen + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image0[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                float bluetop = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtBlue + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image0[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = redtop;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greentop;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = bluetop;
            }
            else if (i != 0 && i != height - 1 && j == 0) //left
            {
                float redleft = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtRed + image0[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image0[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed
                + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image0[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtRed) / 6);
                float greenleft = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtGreen + image0[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image0[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                float blueleft = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtBlue + image0[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image0[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = redleft;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenleft;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueleft;
            }
            else if (i != 0 && i != height - 1 && j == width - 1) //right
            {
                float redright = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image0[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                + image0[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtRed) / 6);
                float greenright = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image0[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                + image0[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                float blueright = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image0[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                + image0[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = redright;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenright;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueright;
            }
            else if (i == height - 1 && j != 0 && j != width - 1) //bottom
            {
                float redbottom = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtRed + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image0[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image0[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                + image0[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                float greenbottom = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtGreen + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                + image0[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                float bluebottom = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtBlue + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                + image0[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = redbottom;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenbottom;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = bluebottom;
            }
            else
            {
                float red = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtRed + image0[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image0[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image0[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed
                + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image0[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image0[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed)
                / 9);
                float green = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtGreen + image0[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image0[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image0[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen)
                / 9);
                float blue = round((float)(image0[i][j].rgbtBlue + image0[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image0[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                + image0[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image0[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image0[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue)
                / 9);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Rather than casting to `float`, you should, for example, divide by `4.0`.

Comment: I'll try that thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code block, you use `image` in round function for three times by mistake. It should be `image0`.

```
 if (i == 0 && j == 0) //topleft
            {
                float red00 = round((float)(image0[0][0].rgbtRed + image0[0][1].rgbtRed + image0[1][1].rgbtRed + image[1][0].rgbtRed) / 4);
                float green00 = round((image0[0][0].rgbtGreen + image0[0][1].rgbtGreen + image0[1][1].rgbtGreen + image[1][0].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                float blue00 = round((image0[0][0].rgbtBlue + image0[0][1].rgbtBlue + image0[1][1].rgbtBlue + image[1][0].rgbtBlue) / 4);
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil,exactly. I fixed that in the answer. Thanks for the feedback. Naming is really confusing. It should rather be `temp`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will make sure to improve the naming next time.